# If A is Turing-reducible to B and B is Turing recognizable then A is Turing recognizable

Tags: turing-machines, turing-recognizable

I believe this is true and I have given a simple proof of this:
If A is Turing-reducible to B then there exists a Turing machine with oracle for B that decides A, because B is Turing-recognizable then by using the oracle for B we can decide A and therefore A is Turing recognizable.

Comment: What's your question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your situation.  What efforts have you made to answer your own question?  If you have a proof, it would be appropriate to share the proof.  We discourage "please check my answer" questions.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.
Consider the language $H$ of the halting problem and let $H'$ be its complement.

$H'$  is Turing reducible to $H$ and $H$ is recognizable, however $H'$ is not recognizable (if $H'$ were recognizable then $H$ would be decidable).